# SVN: Corrupted property in history makes not possible to merge and diff using https protocol

Tags: svn

We moved from svn to https protocol and discovered, that it's not possible to merge show the log and diff anymore.

Here is an example of corrupted chunk in fsfs db/revs file:
...

```
PLAIN
K 13
svn:eol-style
V 6
native
K 38
svn:keywordsate Revision Author URL Id
V 0

END
ENDREP
id: 6-30869.1-22136.r30869/15322
type: file
count: 0
text: 30869 0 431 811 c479187fc252bba6a9a2​93c08c4aa356 0e7d04db842f51488744​6a68d3da03c948083a26​ 30868-ntg/_8
props: 30869 15226 83 0 a7b1e9ee5c7900deedb4​569e6e4715a5
cpath: /MaxPatrol/trunk/Con​sole/PTConsole/Helpe​rs/StringHelper.cs
copyroot: 22136 /MaxPatrol/trunk/Console
```

...

problem is with spaces in property name:

```
svn:keywordsate Revision Author URL Id
```

We have 122 versions and files affected. But can't change it easily.
FSFS file has checksums, offsets and other stuff.

Can anyone please help, how to make changes in these files? What should we recalculate after changes?
Thanks!

PS modifying the dump file could be easier, but it's too large for editing. We can't also change property through cliet, because an error appear.

Comment: A correct repository is not caused by changing access protocols unless you really, really screwed something up. Have you run `svnadmin verify`?

Comment: We changed protocol because of VisualSVN and it's features.

Comment: `svnadmin verify` fixes some errors, but not all

Comment: For example, it shows me, how to fix the checksum, but repo is broken anyway..

Comment: In my original comment, "correct" should be "corrupt."

Comment: You will want to run fsfsverify.py as well then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we've made property modifications in dump file using sed and loaded it again.
Without any checksum/offset/length calculations..